# Spring 5 Data Jpa - OneToOne, new entity, a single insert operation

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one, batching

I have table User entity/table with id as primary key / string / uuid generated value.
I also have UserDetails entity/table with userId as primary key / string / foreign key to user.id. Note that in the UserDetails java entity I don't need the User entity, but user_id is enough.

I'm trying to define the entities in a way that inserting new User entity will also create a new UserDetails row, with the same id.

Any ideas how to implement this?

To clarify, what I want can be achieved in sql by doing this:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES ('auto-generated-uuid-31212', 'Bobby');
INSERT INTO user_details (user_id) VALUES ('auto-generated-uuid-31212');

COMMIT
```

My last attempt was to have 2 columns on UserDetails - String userId with @Id (no other mapping), and User user with OneToOne/JoinColumn(name="userId")/MapsId annotations.

However it seems like spring/hibernate attempts to then save the UserDetails info first rather than together with the User, and I end up getting foreign key constraint fails on the foreign key constraint.

Quick code:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotNull
    @Builder.Default
    private UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private String userId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    @MapsId
    private User user;
}
```

Edit: I forgot to add the UserDetails property on the User to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. Since you have two tables you will need at least two inserts.
Another option is to embed the user details (@Embeddable instead of @Entity on UserDetails and some other changes) but this requires the columns in the user-table. Then you have only one table and can go with a single insert.

```
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private UserDetails details;

    public User(String name)
    {
        userDetails = new UserDetails(this);
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

with UserDetails:

```
public class UserDetails {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "user_id")
   private String userId;

   @OneToOne
   @MapsId
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User user;

   public UserDetails(User user)
   {
       this.user = user;
   }
}
```

Now if you create a user the details are automatically created too and will be persisted to the database along with the user.

Comment: Karsten - I forgot to write the property in my question; I edited and add it.
Do note the `name` in the JoinColumn annotation is the one on the User, because of the OneToOne annotation. See the documentation on JoinColumn for more information.

But to clarify, that exists and the issue is still there.

Comment: @MatanShukry I finally got it working. Not as simple as i thought ... and a bit ugly. OneToMany work much better.

Comment: awesome, that worked. Thank you!

Fyi, I have a followup issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883761/spring-5-data-jpa-onetoone-on-a-specific-literal-property

Comment: HQL insert might be more elegant.